# The mode can have several numbers if there are ties, when a single number is required, what is the correct function to apply?

Tags: statistics, average, descriptive-statistics

The mode can have several numbers if there are ties, what is that best strategy to take a single number - e.g. take the arithmetic mean or median (of the modes)?

Would the geometric mean, harmonic mean, or any other measure of central tendency be a better option?

Note: Excel has a function Mode.Sngl, although the docs doesn't explain how it works mathematically.  Even if it did, I'm not sure it is the best option?

For example, the mode of { 0, 11, 22, 44, 100 } is { 11, 22, 44 }. However, this is not useful for some applications, where a single number must be used.  Therefore, 22 could be selected, as the median, or 25.67 as the mean, or a different type of average.

Comment: A numerical example would improve your question.

Comment: As normally defined, modes are not necessarily unique. If you want a unique answer for all circumstances, you'll have to supply a definition that you want your unique-version-of-the-mode to satisfy.

Comment: Is this an exercise specifically about the mode? Otherwise, can you explain why you are looking at modes? Modes generated by occasional ties seem especially uninteresting. // Your statement `he mode of { 0, 11, 22, 44, 100 } is { 11, 22, 44 }` makes no sense to me. Are there missing commas?

Comment: Sometimes ties come from excessive rounding; Generated 20 obs from NORM(50,sd 3); sorted and rounded to 2 places, then rounded to integers (many ties);  2 place: 42.40, 44.11, 45.05, 45.50, 45.56, 45.57, 47.12, 47.93, 48.34, 48.87, 48.91, 48.96, 49.75, 50.81, 50.94, 51.48, 51.49, 52.17, 53.26, 55.87. Int: 42, 44, 45,  46, 46, 46,  47,  48, 48,  49, 49, 49,  50,  51, 51, 51, 51,  52, 53, 56. For the integers, is it meaningful to say 51 is the mode?